# C# console application create frameless browser window with URL

Tags: c#, console-application

Is there a way to create a frameless browser window from within a C# Console Application?

For instance :

When the user enters a button, a frameless browser window will be created with a given URL... and if so, how can this window interact with the prime console application, I.E. send receive messages.

Is there a way to set dimensions for the new window?

Thanks!

Comment: Not really. Seems like an odd amalgamation of technologies.

Comment: Maybe take a look at Eletron.NET https://github.com/ElectronNET/Electron.NET

Comment: "Not really" is not accurate, there's a way to do most things in software development. Whether it's the 'right' approach or easy to implement or not is another matter. OP - are you open to other approaches? Or are your requirements to build it like this specifically? If the former, provide some more context.

Comment: you have to start your browser app in a new process and then use IPC Inter Process Communication. You could create a WCF service that is accessible by both to share information. You can pass arguments e.g. size and position when starting a process.

Comment: I assumed you would create the browser window yourself by writing a small application. If you want to use e.g. firefox you would need to check browser's config if it supports borderless style and find the appropriate command switches. than you need to write a small service maybe hosted local or on a server. this server or service controls browser contents and handles requests from your console app.